# query in sql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table tickets(username,posts,scheme)
users may have may posts.
for e.g.,

```
____________________________________
username  |    posts   |    scheme |
__________|____________|___________|
A         |    post1   |      10   |
__________|____________|___________|
B         |    post2   |      2    |
__________|____________|___________|
B         |    post 3  |      13   |
__________|____________|___________|
A         |    post 4  |      21   |
__________|____________|___________|
A         |    post 5  |      -1   |
__________|____________|___________|
```

My query should geneate output distinct username with total number of titles and total reputation. i.e.,

```
_______________________
|A   |   3   |   30    |
|____|_______|_________|
|B   |   2   |   15    |
|____|_______|_________|
```

My model function:-

```
function getAllUsers(){                      
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('username,COUNT(title) AS numtitle');
        $this->db->where('site_referers_id',1);
        return $this->db->get('tbl_tickets');
     }
```

but that doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: You need to group by the username also, `$this->db->group_by('username');`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `$this->db->group_by()` instead of `distinct`:

```
function getAllUsers(){                      
  $this->db->select('username, COUNT(*) AS numtitle, SUM(scheme) AS total');
  $this->db->where('site_referers_id',1);
  $this->db->group_by('username');
  return $this->db->get('tbl_tickets');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check this code

```
    $this->db->select('username,COUNT(title) AS numtitle');
    $this->db->where('site_referers_id',1);
     $this->db->group_by('username');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_tickets');
```

you get the perfect result

Answer (score 0):

I know this question asking very ago, But old answers not get attention to author. **Try with the SQL :**

```
$sql ="SELECT count(*),username,SUM(scheme) FROM `tble_one` group by username";
$result = $this->db->query($sql)->get();
```